# How can I fix this react error: module not found error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

This is the source code:

```
import email from '../assets/email.png';
import mobile from '../assets/mobile.png';
import api from '../assets/api.png';
import cpp from '../assets/cpp.png';
import css from '../assets/css.png';
import figma from '../assets/figma.png';
import flutter from '../assets/flutter.png';
import git from '../assets/git.png'; 
import graphql from '../assets/graphql.png'; 
import html from '../assets/html.png';
import javascript from '../assets/javascript.png'; 
import mu5 from '../assets/mu5.png'; 
import node from '../assets/node.png'; 
import python from '../assets/python.png'; 
import react from '../assets/react.png'; 
import redux from '../assets/redux.png'; 
import sass from '../assets/sass.png'; 
import typescript from '../assets/typescript.png'; 
import vue from '../assets/vue.png';
import about01 from '../assets/about01.png'; 
import about02 from '../assets/about02.png'; 
import about03 from '../assets/about03.png'; 
import about04 from '../assets/about04.png'; 
import profile from '../assets/profile.png'; 
import circle from '../assets/circle.svg'; 
import logo from '../assets/logo.png'; 
import adidas from '../assets/adidas.png'; 
import amazon from '../assets/amazon.png'; 
import asus from '../assets/asus.png'; 
import bolt from '../assets/bolt.png'; 
import nb from '../assets/nb.png'; 
import skype from '../assets/skype.png'; 
import spotify from '../assets/spotify.png';

export default {
  email, mobile, api, cpp, css, figma, flutter, git, graphql, html, javascript, mu5, node, python, react, redux, sass, typescript, vue, about01, about02, about03, about04, profile, circle, logo, adidas, amazon, asus, bolt, nb, skype, spotify
};
```

The screenshot of the error is attached below.
[image]

Below is the screenshot of my folder structure.

[image: the screenshot of my folder structure]
the screenshot of my folder structure

[image: the screenshot of my folder structure]
the screenshot of my folder structure

[image]

This is the error/problem vscode displayed: [{
"resource": "/c:/Users/Joshua C. Adumchimma/Documents/01_Web Development/React/Full Stack Portfolio/frontend_react/src/constants/images.js",
"owner": "eslint",
"code": {
"value": "import/no-anonymous-default-export",
"target": {
"$mid": 1,
"external": "https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/v2.26.0/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md",
"path": "/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/v2.26.0/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md",
"scheme": "https",
"authority": "github.com"
}
},
"severity": 4,
"message": "Assign object to a variable before exporting as module default",
"source": "eslint",
"startLineNumber": 38,
"startColumn": 1,
"endLineNumber": 72,
"endColumn": 3
}]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to a wrong path import. The compiler told you that it's not possible to find the module you are searching.

Double check your constants file import.

The `../` means that you are trying to read some file from the parent folder of your file.

For example from a structure like that

```
-Root
--Child1
---File.js
--Child2
---SecondFile.js
---MyFile.js
```

To access the **SeconFile.js** from **MyFile.js** , you have to use `./SecondFile.js` as import path because it's in the same directory.
To access the **File.js** from **MyFile.js** , you have to use `../Child1/SecondFile.js` as import path (access Root directory with `../`) to access the SecondFile.js .

If your structure is like that:

```
-src
--asset
---image.png
---constant.js
```

to import the image.png file you have to write

```
import image from './image.png'
```

or if it's something like that:

```
-src
--constant.js
--asset
---image.png

import image from './asset/image.png'
```

or:

```
-src
--constant
---constant.js
--asset
---image.png

import image from '../asset/image.png'
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. But I actually did import the images like it should (like you also said). This is my folder structure. Root { 1. constants - 1st child (inside constants folder I have images.js where I wrote the codes) 2. assets - 2nd child (inside the assets folder where I have all the images placed/kept.)}

Comment: But it's still giving me that error.

Comment: Can you this in your image component: 
<img src={require('yourPath/yourImage.png')} />

Comment: Can someone assist me with this issue please?

Comment: Did you try that again  <img src={require('yourPath/yourImage.png')} />?